# React Vite Module Federation Expose types

Tags: reactjs, typescript, microservices, vite, webpack-module-federation

I have 3 vite react projects setup currently with module federation and everything is working as it should. The main annoyance is that when using a component in a remote project I get none of the type checking, I guess due to the nature of module federation.

We have a multi repo setup and was wondering if there any ways to get the type checking in the remote projects to work for my exposed components.